# Custom Route for handling Root level pages added using Kentico CMS ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kentico

We're creating a custom site using Kentico CMS. I'm a front-end developer for the most part but I'm lead on this project. I understand most Routing concepts in ASP.NET MVC but I'm not sure what to do about pages that get added at a Root Level since I won't be creating pages it would be the Content Entry person creating them through the UI. So I'm trying to figure out what kind of approach would be best and if there is an option to write a route that could even handle it?

I'm stumped because generally if you have root level pages you would have to define them:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name:"About",
   url: "about",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "About"}
);
```

But in the context of a CMS any number of pages can be added to the root level. Is there some way to feed it a collection of pages that occur from the root down to create the routes?

I'll be very active with this post as I'm proofing out ideas as I come up with them but I really have no idea where to start looking. If I need to provide more information please let me know.

EDIT:
Also, is there a way to make Dynamic Controllers even? Then it could just use the default route for the most part and the controller decide where to send the content.

Comment: Have you worked much with Kentico before?

Comment: @joelmdev No this is my first project, other people have in our team but only using WebForms. This is our first MVC site in Kentico

Comment: I can't speak from experience, as I haven't done an MVC site in Kentico, but I know that Kentico is built on WebForms all the way up to the latest version. The MVC features of Kentico are very much bolt on and [come with some limitations](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Developing+sites+using+the+MVC+framework), and I think most scenarios are still better suited for Portal mode.

Comment: @joelmdev Yeah, I've reviewed that page 100 times ha, that's why I came here to see if anyone has tried to address this issue. It would be the same as working with any CMS not limited to Kentico, you do have full use of MVC because we are using Kentico 8.1. We have a full support development team that's why we take to doing things custom for most things because of our technical standards

Comment: We built several sites with ASPX mode before trying portal mode, and the flexibility offered by portal mode made us regret ever having used ASPX mode- much more flexible for content managers and designers. If leveraging MVC in Kentico is anything like leveraging ASPX, I'd urge you not to use it. However, you can probably pull off what you're looking to do with wildcard routes and calling the controllers directly (they're just classes, after all) but at that point you're kind of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @MadDeveloper sort of but not really. We're using the 'hybrid' approach where we're still using Kentico routing to handle the request. Which isn't the best solution because it adds unwanted latency but it's at least a work around for now

Answer (score 0):

Hey I wrote a blog post about this.  The answer is briefly, "Write a route constraint."  This isn't really a Kentico specific answer, and more of a general ASP.NET MVC thing.

Route constraints will basically define "Pages that I return true for get routed to this controller."  It can look/feel scary to dig in to the more advanced parts of routing in asp, but the code you end up with is generally pretty simple.

https://www.bizstream.com/blog/july-2020/how-to-implement-custom-urls-in-kentico-xperience

So for an example (and only an example, don't use this in prod) if you ONLY wanted root level pages made by a content editor of a type "Client.AboutUsPageType" your route constraint would look like:

```
public class RootLevelAboutUsTypeConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
public bool Match( HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    var alias = values[parameterName].ToString();
    var results = CacheHelper.Cache(cs =>
    {
        var tree = new TreeProvider();
        List<TreeNode> nodes = tree.SelectNodes()
            .WhereLike("NodeAliasPath", alias)
            .Type("Client.AboutUsPageType")
            .OnSite("CorporateSite", true)
            .ToList();


        if (cs.Cached)
        {
            cs.GetCacheDependency = () => CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency($"nodes|CorporateSite");
        }


        return nodes;
    }, new CacheSettings(3600, "pagesnamed|get", alias, "CorporateSite"));


    return results.Any();
}
}
```

You would then add it to your route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name:"About",
  url: "{url}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "About"},
  constraints: new { url = new RootLevelAboutUsConstraint() })
);
```

Again, warning that doing this for every single page type would be awful.  You can and should setup a parameterized route constraint that can be reused between actions.  Read the blog post and you should be able to get it down to:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{nodeName:nodealias(Client.AboutUsPageType)}")]
    public ActionResult About(string nodeName)
    {
        return View(nodeName);
    }
}
```